# Flutter: Keyboard not showing on TextField after hot reloading

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

I am not sure why the keyboard is not showing after hot reload, I ran the below code which gives empty TextFiled without  **autofocus: true**

```
 TextField field = new TextField(
      controller: controller,
);
```

But Afer adding **autofocus: true** strong text** the keyboard should show as stateful widget will re-draw themselves after hot-reloading.

```
 TextField field = new TextField(
          controller: controller,
          autofocus: true,
    );
```

Note: I am having only TextWidget on my current screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **Hot restart** to recreate all widgets, with hot restart keyboard will be showing automatically. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6p4r.png)

Hot restart shortcut on mac: Cmd + Shift + \